# Pass in Values to Salesforce Community Create Record Form via URL

Tags: lightning-community, url, urlhacking, form, create-records

I'm trying to prepopulate values on a Salesforce Community create record page based on a URL params.

Use Case: `https://<salesforce_url>.sandbox.my.site.com/customers/s/createrecord/Incident?Subject=SubjectName`

I have found this documentation https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm&release=224&type=5, but it's not applicable for Lightning Community. Maybe there is some work around which works for Lightning Community?